# Passing variable to grep in shell

Tags: linux, bash, variables, grep

I have written the following shell to count the number of lines starting with the pattern of " A valA B valB". However, I think that I have not passed variables properly. Any help to fix that?

```
for i in {0..16};
do
    for j in {0..16}; 
    do
        echo A $i B $j 
        grep '^ A : "$i" B : "$j"' file | wc -l
    done
done
```

Comment: Are the double-quotes part of the text to be matched, or is that an attempt at triggering variable expansion?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use proper [bash quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html). Variables are not expanded inside `''`. See the link for reference.

```
grep "^ A : $i B : $j" file | wc -l
```

Also perhaps you mean this, but just try either.

```
grep "^ A : \"$i\" B : \"$j\"" file | wc -l
```

Answer (score 8):

1. You need right shell quoting (use double quotes for shell's variable expansion)
2. You don't need `wc -l`, you can directly use `grep -c` for counting the matches

You can use:

```
grep -c "^ A : $i B : $j" file
```